# Super Key Inactive

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Why do I have to press the 9 dots in the bottom left to *show all applications*?

How can I do it with the <kbd>Super</kbd> key?

At first I could do it, but suddenly it stopped working that way; now my <kbd>Super</kbd> key does nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include your Ubuntu release and desktop session type? If you're unsure, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run the commands `lsb_release -a` and `pgrep -lu "$USER" session` and copy and paste their output into your question. Thanks.

Comment: What does super key do right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd> shows "*Activities*" overview by default. If you want to see the list of applications (simulate what pressing the 9 dots in the bottom left does) you need to press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.